# knockout js: parameters in templated bindings

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jquery-templates

Im trying to template some components often used in my project. To omit the introduced redundancy in html content. However i didnt figure it out if it is even possible to do so.

I have a template like:

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="somefieldtemplate" >  
<input  name=" Prefix" type="text" data-bind="value: ${ $item.fieldName}SomeField" /> 
   ..... mor contents ... 
</script>
```

The parameter bound to the input component shall be adjustable as someone may see via template options so i have an entry like

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'somefieldtemplate', 
         templateOptions: 
             { fieldName:'somefield', displayName:'somefieldlabel' } }">
```

The error message in my console log is:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

I narrowed the problem down to the fact that if i remove `$item.fieldName` with its value it works.

Has anybody an enlightening solution to this problem maybe ?

Edit:

As information im currently using knockout.js in version: `knockout-latest`

Comment: Inside of data-binds you can access the available variables directly, so you can just do something like `data-bind="value: $data[$item.fieldName]"

Comment: Thanks for this comment. It was not the exact solution to the problem however it gave me the right direction to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly i need to answer it myself. But i managed to get it working. Thanks to the tip of RP Niemeyer.

For everyone interested in this:

Observables are generated dynamically in the model `someModel` with a register component method. This observables have always names like `<field>SomeField`

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="somefieldtemplate" >  
<input  name="${$item.fieldName}Prefix" type="text" data-bind="value: someModel[$item.fieldName + 'SomeField']" /> 
   ..... more contents ... 
</script>
```

Template-Binding:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'somefieldtemplate', 
         templateOptions: 
             { fieldName:'somefield', displayName:'somefieldlabel' } }">
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after struggling a lot, I solved it by moving to knockout 1.3 beta (now it's in RC) which doesn't use external templating engines. It doesn't support `templateOptions` either but that's not a problem. I just constructed a custom data for the template which contains the main data as a property plus other properties that contain the stuff I would have passed in templateOptions in 1.2. I passed it in the `data` parameter, and everything worked fine.

Comment: May you post some stub code which demonstrates how you managed it to have a template with dynamic bindings inside `data-bind`.

Comment: I can, but not until this evening, as it resides on my home pc and I'm at work now. Dunno your timezone but it'll be in no less than 6/7 hours from now. If you can wait that much, I'll be happy to help.

Comment: If you would be so kind i would appreciate it ;).

Comment: Alright, I'll make a reminder to do that once I get home. I'll update my post with the code sample. Check back l8r :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
data-bind="value: ${fieldName} + 'SomeField'"
```

Comment: I tested this also this does not work. `data-bind` evaluation is different from any other attribute in `knockout.js`. If you put the same code to a different attribute it will work that's true but not inside data-bind.